# Running system command with argument in a PostgreSQL function

Tags: linux, database, postgresql, function, triggers

I'm not sure if I was specific in the question, but I'm having trouble creating a Postgres function that runs a Linux shell command, with one detail: it's a function in a Trigger after insert and I need to use some `NEW` columns.

While in MySQL, using the plugin "MySQL UDF" it was pretty simple, trigger worked like this:

```
BEGIN
 DECLARE result int(10);
 SET result = sys_exec('/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/.../regras.php NEW.uniqueid NEW.linkedid NEW.eventtype');
END
```

But on PostgreSQL I tried the language PL/sh, which enables running any shell script, so I wrote the following function:

```
   CREATE FUNCTION tarifador_func2() RETURNS TRIGGER
    LANGUAGE plsh
    AS $$
    #!/bin/sh
    /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/...regras.php NEW.uniqueid NEW.linkedid NEW.eventtype
   $$;
```

It does execute the .php file in proper way, the problem is the language does not recognize the `NEW` variables I'm giving as arguments to the PHP, so in the `args[]` what I got is `"NEW.uniqueid"`, `"NEW.linkedid"` and `"NEW.eventtype"`.

So, anyone knows how can I properly use the `NEW` argument in PL/sh?
Another possible solution might be to manually set the three values I need via the arguments on crating the trigger, but it's not allowed to use `NEW` in the arguments.

Comment: an you please help with my similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61071706/running-system-command-in-plsql-and-use-return-value-in-insert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access **some** values in plsh triggers.

- UPDATE offers only OLD
- INSERT offers only NEW (duh)
- DELETE I didn't test

So you get those values using arguments, like $1, $2

You function would look kinda like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION tarifador_func2() RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE plsh
AS $$
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/...regras.php $3 $6 $1
```

$$;

Notice that I didn't use `$1 $2 $3`, that is because `plsh` extension dumps **ALL** columns into arguments in order they are declared in your table. So you might do something like `INSERT INTO table1 (column3) VALUES (6);` and it will be under `$3` in `plsh`, assuming this is third column in table.

As a side note, metadata of trigger is available thru env vars.

Comment: `DELETE` should also report the `OLD` record as parameters. (because for all trigger events, [it uses](https://github.com/petere/plsh/blob/a5b310ff397f8178292762b8a353d315efd67644/plsh.c#L458) the [`tg_trigtuple` property](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/trigger-interface.html)). -- Another side note that if the trigger definition has fixed parameters too, they will come before the column values (these seem to be extremely undocumented).

Comment: @Lukasz I have a command that return ankit\nankit1 as value(\n is new line) but i want to use these value to insert into other table. Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you cannot access the `NEW`and `OLD` tuple in PL/sh.

I would use [PL/Perl](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plperl-triggers.html) or [PL/Python](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpython-trigger.html) for this purpose.

Here is an example in PL/Python:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pytrig() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpythonu AS
$$import os
os.system("/usr/bin/php /home/laurenz/hello.php '" + TD["new"]["val"] + "'")$$;

CREATE TABLE test (id integer PRIMARY KEY, val text);

CREATE TRIGGER pytrig AFTER INSERT ON test FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE pytrig();
```

Comment: I did try using PL/Python, but had no success on executing "subprocess.call", would you have an example of running the php file?

Comment: I have added a simple example. I am no Python expert though.

Comment: Thank you @laurenz-albe, your solution is also correct for my question.