# AFTER UPDATE trigger on Postgresql with pl/sh language problem

Tags: postgresql, triggers

Based on the answers from [Running system command with argument in a PostgreSQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43205594/running-system-command-with-argument-in-a-postgresql-function) and few days research and testing, I confirmed that PL/SH does not support getting new trigger data when UPDATE. So I decided to create one more table to get the NEW data when UPDATE.

The flow is following:

DB-A table1 (Logical Replicate)-> DB-B table1 (after update trigger insert OR update)-> DB-C table 2(after trigger fired) , WHEN update to server, in after update trigger function, I connect to DB-B table1 again to get the result following the primary key, I expect to get the NEW data which is the after updated data on DB-B table 1 but I still get the OLD data which is the data before update.

Based on documentation of Postgres:

The trigger can be specified to fire before the operation is attempted on a row (before constraints are checked and the INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE is attempted); or after the operation has completed (after constraints are checked and the INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE has completed); or instead of the operation (in the case of inserts, updates or deletes on a view).

I am very confused because the after update trigger is fired after the UPDATE isn't  it?

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/sh

(   
    echo "OPR=${PLSH_TG_OP}"
    echo "TB=${PLSH_TG_TABLE_SCHEMA}.${PLSH_TG_TABLE_NAME}"
    
    tabledt="TBRD="
    for arg 
    do
        tabledt="$tabledt$arg "
    done
    
    echo $tabledt
    echo $PLSH_TG_WHEN;
    
    echo $(PGPASSWORD=xxx psql testslave xx -X -At -c "select * from table1 where id = $1")
    
    
) | /home/xx/test/transition
```

Please help and any suggestion? Thankyou.

Comment: It seems that you have to use a trigger BEFORE UPDATE, then throw an exception in the function. The update should not happen.

Comment: I also try the BEFORE UPDATE but still get OLD data